# How to merge a child arrays based on a common header field using dataweave 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am looking for dataweave where I am trying to merge the arrays based on a particular field in the header.

Below is the input, I am trying to merge the items array based on the shipmentId or orderId field.

Input:

```
[
  {
    "orderId": 7810,
    "shipmentId": "2201",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 2170354,
        "shippedQuantity": 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "orderId": 7810,
    "shipmentId": "2201",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 2170355,
        "shippedQuantity": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "orderId": 7811,
    "shipmentId": "4457",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 2170348,
        "shippedQuantity": 4
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "orderId": 7810,
    "shipmentId": "2201",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 2170354,
        "shippedQuantity": 4
      },
      {
        "id": 2170355,
        "shippedQuantity": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "orderId": 7811,
    "shipmentId": "4457",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 2170348,
        "shippedQuantity": 4
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question is unclear. You say "I am trying to merge the arrays based on a particular field in the header." however then you don't define which field but say it can be any of "the shipmentId or orderId field.". Which one is it? Or is it both with some more detailed criteria that is not mentioned? Even the title says "a common header field", not two. Please update your question to be more clear and define the problem in an unambiguous way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupBy`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-groupby) to group the array on basis of `orderId_shipmentId` to get unique value (or you can use any of them if that's what your requirement is). It will give you an object with the key as the resulting `orderId_shipmentId` and value as the grouped array of the matching items. Then you can [`pluck`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.3/dw-core-functions-pluck) the values to get the desired output.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload groupBy ($.orderId ++ '_' ++ $.shipmentId)
pluck ((groupedOrders) -> {
    shipmentId: groupedOrders.shipmentId[0],
    orderId: groupedOrders.orderId[0],
    items: flatten(groupedOrders.items)
})
```